# How can i bind a directive to a function in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I have created a simple offClick directive in angular2, which works, like so.

```
import { Directive, Host, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[offClick]',
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
    }
})

export class OffClickDirective {
    @Input('offClick') a;

    @Output('off')
    offClicked = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef) {

    }

    onClick($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();

        if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains($event.target))
            this.offClicked.emit({});
    }
}
```

But to add this to a HTML element, i have to do something like this.

```
<div [offClick] (off)="onOffClick($event)"></div>
```

Is there anyway that i can change this directive, so i can use it like this on a HTML element

```
<div (offClick)="onOffClick($event)"></div>
```

OR

I basically dont want to have to declare a tag for the directive and then another to catch the event....

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't seem to use `@Input('offClick')`. What is it for?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[offClick]',
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
    }
})

export class OffClickDirective {
    @Output('offClick')
    offClicked = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef) {

    }

    onClick($event) {
        $event.stopPropagation();

        if (!this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains($event.target))
            this.offClicked.emit({});
    }
}
```

```
<div (offClick)="onOffClick($event)"></div>
```

Comment: Thought i tried this, but obviously not, worked perfectly thank you!!